# No SUPER privilege; Max packet size exceeded

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, python-2.7, mysql-python

I'm trying to build a mySQL database using mysql.connector, sqlalchemy, and pandas. I'm able to create the database, set up a few tables, and assign primary keys. I just got to the point where I needed to put one of my larger tables into the database. I attempt the following:

```
full_gencode_df.to_sql(name='full_gencode_df', con=engine, index=True)
```

Which yields the following error (Apologies for the horizontal scroll, it's a long error, even truncated):

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError) 1153 (08S01): Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes [SQL: u'INSERT INTO full_gencode_df (`index`, ccdsid, end, exon_id, exon_number, ....
```

After looking around for solutions, from what I can tell this is an error on the SQL end, not the Python end, and the solution would be to change `max_allowed_packet` to allow larger packets to be inserted into the database. Unfortunately, I do not have `SUPER` privilege on the database server, and I don't know what the chances of me getting it is.

I was unable to find a workaround that doesn't involve having `SUPER` privilege. Is there a workaround, either on the Python end, or the SQL end? Would attempting to chunk the table and write to it in `append` mode help?

Comment: Chunking and appending helps. That's what I have done in the past a couple of times, at least. Looking forward to other alternatives, if any.

Comment: Just confirming that I've tested it now, and chunking does allow me to get the table into the database, but I still am curios if there's a faster/better way to do this.